# Does a uniform load under an object affects the object?

Tags: forces

I am having a problem in understanding whether the uniform load under and object affects the object. Here is a sketch of what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fweog.jpg

If you look at the sketch; the uniform load is under a square object. Should I include the concentrated(UL*Distance) force on the summation of Y to find the value of By and Ay? Or the UL doesn’t affect the object and it shouldn’t be used on the summation of Y and summation of Moment. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purpose of determining the reactions at A and B, you can consider the object a rigid body that will not undergo deformation due to any of the loads. As long as the problem is statically determinant, you can replace the distributed load with a single equivalent concentrated load without considering deformations.

But if and when you want to draw shear and moment diagrams after determining reactions, you must put back the distributed load.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes it is a static rigid body. What does the uniform load represent? Is it the load it gives per meter of distance? Like is it the load the box exerts downwards?

Comment: In your description you made it sound like an external distributed downward load. But generally in problems like this, the distributed "load" shown in your diagram would represent the uniformly distributed weight of the structure (e.g, weight of a beam). It doesn't matter as far as the static equilibrium requirements are concerned.

Comment: So it means that it is the weight of the box being uniformly distributed downward, right? And thus it should be included in the sum of forces along Y.

Comment: @Bido362 Yes it should be included in the sum of the forces in the y direction. What it represents doesn’t matter. Since there is no downward force shown through the center of gravity of the object it could represent the weight of the object. Alternatively it could be an external load, and the weight considered negligible. Normally however it would be shown on top not underneath.  Bottom line it doesn’t matter. It just needs to be included.